# Sugar CRM Accounts Table index muddled

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

I have inherited a rather awful setup of SugarCRM (v7) to try to support. The database keeps playing up with error messages for example:

```
2015-04-27 07:44:49 7f68755bc700 InnoDB: Error: page 3 log sequence number 161677395
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 72461969.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb- recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

Looking at the data I find some of the id are numeric and some MD5.

Could this mismatch be causing a continual error? Why on earth have an id as a char(36) rather than a simple numeric?

Answer (score 0):

Regards the char(36) field for the ID field, this page may help with understanding that: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Databases/